# Automatically Rotoscope a transparent background?

Tags: texturing, transparency

I have a pixelated texture that is transparent. I want to actually remove the transparent background so that there is no real transparency, just a rotoscoped object. This is difficult to do manually, as the texture is pixelated. Is there a feature or add on to do this for me?